# Android : Mistake with Intent and Activities

Tags: android, android-intent

I've 3 activities A, B and C.

With A, I'm calling B, and with B I'm calling C. (every times with a sample Button).

I wanted to call the Activity A, with the C's button so I wrote that :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, A.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
startActivity(intent);
```

It works, but I want to send an information to the A activity. So I added that :

```
intent.putExtra("id", object.getId());
```

But in the A Activity, I don't succeed to have this data....

I tried to do that on the A Activity when I call the B Activity :

```
startActivityForResult(i, 1);
```

But when I'm on the C activity, and I click on the button, I'm entering in :

```
onActivityResult
```

but the Intent data is null. (because it's excepting to be called from B Activity ?)

How can I "give" an information C -> A ?

Thanks,

Comment: Can't you just manage your Task stack and go back to the A activity that is already there? I suppose the id would be the same. That would be the equivalent of pressing Back twice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `startActivity()` should work. Override `onNewIntent(Intent intent)` in Activity A and check for the data there.

Comment: Thanks ! Correct answer :) I will accept in few minutes.